# I am not getting error message when validation fails in spring boot hibernate validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I have created a simple Spring Boot application and I want to apply hibernate validation. But I don't get errors message. I get only below message if validation fails

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-11T09:51:55.695+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/users/"
}
```

my domain code is below

```
   @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16)
    private String password;
```

my controller

```
@PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<UserRest> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) {
        UserRest userRest = new UserRest();
        userRest.setFirstName(userDetails.getFirstName());
        userRest.setLastName(userDetails.getLastName());
        userRest.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
        return new ResponseEntity<UserRest>(userRest, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do Bean Validation with Hibernate Validation in Spring Boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229062/how-to-do-bean-validation-with-hibernate-validation-in-spring-boot-app)

Comment: NO , i know we can manually create controll advice and throw response entity from there  . but internally if any validation fails spring boot creates that response for us .  I am getting that error response as show above . but without any error message . :( why spring boot not create any message or errors stack in above message ? @Krisz

Comment: Spring does not create a sensible HTTP response for you when using hibernate validator, you have to manually do that, like in the link above.